# Use Threads for cells in custom grid

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, winforms, threadpool

I'm having WPF application with custom control like grid(let assume which has 100 rows and 10 columns) and it has formulas in more cells.
I'm having own logic for parsing and computation formulas from those cells one by one. 
It working fine but it takes more time. 
So i decided to use multi-threading for parsing cells simultaneously.

I don't have experience in multi-threading. I have tried **Thread class** and **ThreadPool** for this but i don't know how to implement this.

Here i provided the overview of my code,

1. UpdateCell --> Entry point of each cell
2. Here invoke --> string parsedString = Parse("cellText");

Please guide me, where i can use MultiThreading either in UpdateCell or Parse method and help me how to use Threads or ThreadPool here.

```
    Public void UpdateCell(object cell)
    {
       string ParsedString = Parse(grid, cellText);
//How to use threads here? I tried ThreadPool here, but grid gets disposed after thread execution. so that it leads crashing.
    //some codes
    }

    public string Parse(string formulaText)
    {
    //Parsing logic    (How to use threads here? Here i tried threads but it returns empty string immediately.)
    return formulaText; 
    }
```

Thanks,

Comment: I advice you to use Tasks. Here is an example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/async

Comment: @Sasha In my app. users can set the thread count for parsing logic. so that i tried ThreadPool.

Comment: Use thread to parse values - I would say it is not the best idea. Read here about differences between Thread and Task https://www.dotnetforall.com/difference-task-and-thread/

Comment: Don't use threads or tasks - you can't mix these with user controls. You must only use the main UI thread when accessing, updating, or creating controls. Only use threads and tasks with non-UI objects.

Comment: @Sasha - You can't use another thread other than the UI thread to update the UI. So if a task uses another thread then you can't use it to update a user control.

Comment: @Enigmativity Yes, but you can use for example observableCollection and propertry BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization. (will marshal events from background thread to UI thread.) So yes, it will be updated from the main UI thread, but all work will be done at the background. That is what I mean

Comment: @Sasha - What you said was "you can update userControls from task' which is nothing like your your second response. Can you see that this would be misleading?

Answer (score -1):

It is better to use Tasks over Threads. Try this code

```
public async Task<bool> UpdateCellAsync(object cell)
{
     string parsedString = await ParseAsync("cellText");         
     //if no errors - return true, else - false
     return true;
}

public async Task<string> ParseAsync(string formulaText)
{
     // if you have async methods, then await methodAsync();
     // or create or task/tasks
     await Task.Run(() => //your code in separate thread. );
     //other stuff to do
     return formulaText
}
```